# How to enumerate strings in a string resources file?

Tags: android

I have a resources file called string.xml in res/valus directory

the file has many string resources

how can I obtain these items in an array from code ?

I tried

```
Field[] x=R.string.class.getFields();
```

but it does not work.

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I want to add the strings to a ListView

Comment: Keep in mind you can also declare an array of strings into your strings.xml: 
<string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: Thanks
But My resources are in the form
<item name"abc">some value</item>

so using string arrays would not be suitable to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me.
You might detail your problem a little more though - what doesn't work?
Note that the R.string class contains ints, not strings. Are you expecting strings? If you want a string from that resourceId int, call `Context.getString(resourceId)`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try again and tell you the result

Comment: Alright my problem was I used to display the length of the array like this txt.setText(x.length); it didn't throw a compile error but threw a runtime error but when wrote it like this txt.setText(String.valueOf(x.length)); it worked just fine.
silly mistake indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example of enumaration strings.You can use it.

```
Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
    for(final Field field : fields) {
       String name = field.getName(); //name of string
       try{
           int id = field.getInt(R.string.class); //id of string
       }catch (Exception ex) {
           //do smth
       }
    }
```